# Как отредактировать повторяюшийся код в каждом из фаилов

Tags: phpstorm, текст

Проблема в том что мне досталось поддерживать один сайт который отвратительно написан. Есть порядка 40-50 фаилов где повторяется одну и тоже меню. Надо убрать пару пунктов и изменить ссылки. Что подскажите? Нет ли специальных утилит в каком -нибудь PhpStorm? Или же каких то сторонних

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R

Comment: проще удалить эти одинаковые куски и заменить на include хотя-бы.

Comment: Очень долго это. Я пожалуй немного приуменьшил количество страниц.

Comment: @Not even close, можно регуляркой выцепить все это меню и заменить на тот самый инклюд.

Comment: К сожалению не владею нужными знаниям по поводу регулярок

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + R не помогает)

Comment: @Not even close, мы не можем просто так взять и научить регуляркам или выплавить серебряную пулю, не видя, против чего она предназначается.

Comment: Мне кажется без регулярок никак, например в Notepad++ есть возможность использовать регулярки при поиске с заменой, причем сразу во всех документах. Я, когда понадобилось регулярку написать, пользовался подобными этому [regexpr.ru][1] сервисами для их проверки.


  [1]: http://regexpr.ru/

Answer (score 6):

**Ctrl + Shift + R** — Замена По заданному пути, хоть по всему проекту.

Answer (score 1):

Ну или найти и заменить. Хоть в файле, хоть по всему проекту)) **Ctrl + H**, **Ctrl + F** иногда встречается

Comment: Это работает только рамках одного файла. С шифтом, по заданному пути.

Comment: В ST2 есть пункт меню "найти и заменить в проекте" а проект это дерево файлов и папок в указанной директории